# PHP running 1 query for multiple variables from array

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

Using the below code in an attempt to run a single query with exploded array variables:

```
 <?php
 $containers = $_POST['cntnum'];
 $containersArray = preg_replace('/\n$/','',preg_replace('/^\n/','',preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',"\n",$containers)));
 $count = count($containersArray);

 for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
 {
   $container = $containersArray[$i];
   $cntFixed = "'".$container."',";
 }

 $select = "SELECT container, date, pool FROM inventory WHERE container IN (".$ctnFixed.")";

 $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die(mysqli_error());

 ?>
```

When I pass $cntFixed into the query.  I don't get all of the variables that were in the array.  Instead, I only get the last of the variables with an ending comma, as shown when I print to the console here:

```
  "SELECT container, date, pool FROM inventory WHERE container IN ('variable3',)"
```

Of course, the ending comma will throw the query off, so I need to take that into consideration.

I cannot put the query into the for loop, because that runs the query the same amount of times as the array count.

What I need to do is run the query 1 time with all of the variables passed into the query.

The query should look like this when I print it to the console:

```
 "SELECT container, date, pool FROM inventory WHERE container IN ('variable1', 'variable2', 'variable3')"
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create an array, then [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it into a string. You seem to already have your data in `$containersArray`, so use that, unless you need to build another array for some reason. Then add it in like this:

```
 $select = "SELECT container, date, pool FROM inventory WHERE container IN ('".implode("','",$containersArray."')";
```

Please note this is not secure and can open you up to both SQL injection and nasty quoting issues. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), and you can build up the placeholders the same way.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `.=` operator,

PHP documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Then remember to delete the last `,`